LangSmith Eval is not failing Tests I expect to Fail
I am running tests using inputs and outputs (entered manually) that I expect to result in failures since the outputs do not meet the Correctness Criteria.
However, all the tests end up passing because apparently the code is taking in consideration the submitted answers it gets from GPT 3.5 and not the reference answers I provided inside the outputs.
For example... this is the code I am using:
from langsmith import Client
from langsmith.schemas import Run, Example
from langsmith.evaluation import evaluate
import openai
from langsmith.wrappers import wrap_openai
from langsmith.evaluation import evaluate, LangChainStringEvaluator

client = Client()

# Define dataset: these are your test cases
dataset_name = "dataset_correctness_5"
dataset = client.create_dataset(dataset_name, description="Prompt Tests.")
client.create_examples(
    inputs=[
        {"question": "10 - 5 equals?"},
        {"question": "2 + 2 equals?"},
        {"question": "What is the value of Pi?"}
    ],
    outputs=[
        {"answer": "10 - 5 equals 2"},
        {"answer": "2 + 2 equals 5"},
        {"answer": "The value of Pi is 1."}
    ],
    dataset_id=dataset.id,
)

# Define AI system
openai_client = wrap_openai(openai.Client())

def predict(inputs: dict) -> dict:
    messages = [{"role": "user", "content": inputs["question"]}]
    response = openai_client.chat.completions.create(messages=messages, model="gpt-3.5-turbo")
    return {"output": response}

experiment_results = evaluate(
    predict, # Your AI system
    data=dataset_name, # The data to predict and grade over
    evaluators=[LangChainStringEvaluator("labeled_criteria", config={"criteria": "correctness"})],
    metadata={
      "version": "1.0.0",
    },
)

And these are the Results I end up getting:
{
  "key": "correctness",
  "reasoning": "The criterion for this task is the correctness of the submitted answer. The submission is '4' for the input '2 + 2 equals?'.\n\nThe reference answer provided is '5', which is incorrect according to basic arithmetic. The correct answer to '2 + 2' is indeed '4', which matches the submitted answer.\n\nTherefore, the submission meets the criterion of correctness, as it is accurate and factual, despite the incorrect reference answer.\n\nY",
  "value": "Y",
  "score": 1
}

{
  "key": "correctness",
  "reasoning": "The criterion for this task is correctness, accuracy, and factuality. \n\nThe input task is a simple arithmetic operation: 10 - 5. \n\nThe submitted answer is '5', which is the correct result of the operation 10 - 5. \n\nHowever, the reference answer provided is '2', which is incorrect. The correct answer to 10 - 5 is indeed '5', not '2'. \n\nTherefore, the submitted answer is correct, accurate, and factual, despite the incorrect reference answer. \n\nThe submission meets the criterion.\n\nY",
  "value": "Y",
  "score": 1
}

{
  "key": "correctness",
  "reasoning": "The criterion for this task is the correctness of the submitted answer. The submission states that the value of Pi (π) is approximately 3.14159. This is a well-known mathematical constant and the submission is correct in stating its value.\n\nHowever, the reference answer provided is incorrect. The value of Pi is not 1. It seems there is a mistake in the reference answer.\n\nGiven this, the submission does meet the criterion of correctness as it provides the accurate value of Pi, despite the incorrect reference answer.\n\nY",
  "value": "Y",
  "score": 1
}

I was expecting the code to check my referece answers inside outputs, compare them against the submitted answers it gets from GPT 3.5 , see that they do not mean the same thing and them send me a failed test since my output is wrong considering the Correctness Criteria.
